# Simplifying $\frac1{a(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac1{b(b-c)(b-a)}+\frac1{c(c-a)(c-b)}$ without opening brackets using interpolation theorems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I have such expression:
$$\frac{1}{a(a - b)(a-c)} + \frac{1}{b(b-c)(b - a)} + \frac{1}{c(c - a)(c-b)}$$

I need to use interpolation in order to simplify it and I basically have no idea how.

Comment: Can you provide context? What do you want to simplify this to?

Comment: With $P(x)=x(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, you can use a decomposition of $1/P(x)$ in simple fractions :
$$\frac{1}{P(x)}=\frac{A}{x-a}+\frac{B}{x-b}+\frac{C}{x-c}+\frac{D}{x}$$
where $A,B,C$ are the terms in your expression, and $D=-1/abc$. Then multiply by $x$ and let $x\to \infty$.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan  well, to something like $\frac{1}{abc}$.

Comment: @Kelenner You should write your comment as an answer. I would immediately upvote it.

Comment: @ Jean Marie : Done, thanks...

Answer (score 2):

With $P(x)=x(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, you can use a decomposition of $1/P(x)$ in simple fractions :
$$\frac{1}{P(x)}=\frac{A}{x-a}+\frac{B}{x-b}+\frac{C}{x-c}+\frac{D}{x}$$
where $A,B,C$ are the terms in your expression (for example, to find $A$, you multiply by $x-a$, simplify and take $x=a$), and $D=-1/abc$. Then multiply by $x$ and let $x\to \infty$ and we are done.

Comment: @cosmos5 I think that this method is "decomposition in simple fractions method"  and perhaps not "interpolation method", So this is perhaps not what the OP want...

Comment: I see. Thanks, I got something to read :)